# EXCEL VBA: how to count scenarios?

Tags: excel, vba, scenarios

I am finishing a project and seems like the last part is the most difficult.

I have 7 (6 + 1 optional) columns that have this sort data (some of them have only earlier/later/na, and some of them earlier/later/equals/na). For example three rows:

```
OK OK       No  Yes Earlier Earlier N/A
OK OK       No  Yes Earlier Earlier Earlier
OK Missed   Yes Yes Later   Later   Earlier
```

These can end in 13 different scenarios (if it's "ok ok no yes earlier earlier n/a" would come to for example "a = a + 1"). What I need is to actually count how many of each scenario happened (from "a" to "m"). Also for example if the first three columns are "OK OK OK" I dont need to consider the following conditions and straight add it to f.e. b = b + 1 and go to the next row.

My question here is how efficiently I can do that having in mind that I will have more than 50,000 rows? I understand that I could do that with IF, but I would just get lost in all the if's and I believe this will take a lot of time for macro to run through all the scenarios.

I appreciate all your help and support.

Comment: At first it seems like you just want to count all unique combinations, but then you say `OK OK OK` should be treated differently. Is that the only scenario which gets special treatment?  Seems like you could do this with a formula by concatenating the values in the 7 columns (with a check for `OK OK OK` to screen those out)

Comment: Hello Tim, as I mentioned there are 13 different endings, for example "OK OK NO OK Earlier Later Later" gives 5th scenario (and I need to count this scenario as  + 1) so after all 50,000 rows will run, I will have the number of how many times each scenario happened. What I meant with "OK OK OK" - if first three columns are OK there is no need to inspect other fields as this will count as 1st scenario (a= a +1). 1st scenario for example will be "a - jobs finished on time"

Comment: In that case, you can use a formula to create a new concatenated column and count the distinct entries in that column.

Comment: You mean a column and treat all OK as 1, no as 2, earlier as 3 and etc? and have like 1312123, and later count count all of the needed? Isnt there any other fast simple way?

Comment: I think he means creating a reference column that combines the values of the other columns of the same row, this is easier to count occurrences of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is a starter using the Excel SubTotal function within VBA

It has assumptions built-in to the code which you may want to change, including that the 'solution' is currently in the same sheet as the data (currently in a sheet called "Scenarios", starting in col A and row 7).  This works with a limited amount of data but to 50k rows worth!  You can add code to summarise the statistics as you wish and remove the subtotals.  It leaves the original data intact.

```
Sub scenarios()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strow As Long, endrow As Long, stcol As Long, endcol As Long
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim newstr As String
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range, drng As Range
Dim strArr() As String

strow = 7
stcol = 1  'Col A
endcol = 7 '7 variables

Set ws = Sheets("Scenarios")

    With ws
        'find last data row
        endrow = Cells(Rows.Count, stcol).End(xlUp).Row
            'for each data row
            For r = strow To endrow
                newstr = ""
                'produce concatenated string of that row
                For c = stcol To endcol
                    newstr = newstr & .Cells(r, c)
                Next c
                'put string into array
                ReDim Preserve strArr(r - strow)
                strArr(r - strow) = newstr
            Next r
        'put array to worksheet
        Set drng = .Range(.Cells(strow, endcol + 4), .Cells(endrow, endcol + 4))
        drng = Application.Transpose(strArr)
        'sort newly copied range
        drng.Sort Key1:=.Cells(strow, endcol + 4), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

        'provide a header row for SubTotal
        .Cells(strow - 1, endcol + 4) = "Header"
        'resize range to include header
        drng.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(drng.Rows.Count + 1, drng.Columns.Count).Select
        'apply Excel SubTotal function
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlCount, Totallist:=Array(1)

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello,I have never seen this one before. Where does it count the scenarios? thanks!

Comment: Run the code and it will generate a sorted list adjacent to your data and apply subtotals at each change.  Scroll down this list and you will find a subtotal count under each group or change in scenario.  At present you will need to scroll the whole list, but as I indicated in my answer, if it works for you, we can add code to extract these subtotals into a tidy summary somewhere and remove the subtotals.  Have you run it yet and if so how long does it take?

Comment: Actually it may be easier for you to collapse the subtotal list by using the +/1 buttons that are generated on the LH side of the screen. Click each of the '-' buttons in the level two column.