# microsoft excel counting word based on condition and matcting

Tags: excel, function

in column A there are some name like a,b,c,d (almost thousand) and in column B there are value either x/X or nothing.

now i want to count for name a how many x/X he has. note that may be user will use x or X(capital)

is it possible to use function. i tried this one `SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A18,A1:A17)>0,(b1:b17=x or X )*1,0))` but not working. can any one guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data [see here](http://www.contextures.com/xlSort01.html) and then apply SubTotals [see here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-HP010342620.aspx)

**EDIT**

If you need to do it in code, the rudiments of the approach (using a different example can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411128/excel-vba-how-to-count-scenarios/26415247#26415247)

Comment: i have to count automatically using formula or refresh the data file.

Comment: OK so do the same thing in code.  See my edit to my answer with an example.